# Servlet With HTML/Javascript Does Not Show Anything Outside My Network

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, post, highcharts

I have a web-app that returns full HTML pages with Highcharts Javascript, here is an example http://ldvapp07.fao.org:8030/charts/axis2-web/POSTTest.jsp and the problem itself, because I can see the results inside my network but not from outside of it.

I have other web-apps on the same URL and I can use all of them, there is no proxy and no particular firewall rules.

The servlet returns HTML with the MIME-Type text/html and works perfectly inside the network, but it loads indefinitely outside of it: is there any restriction for servlets with Javascript? Do I need to set something particular in the servlet? Do I need to implement some particular rule in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the full screen graph on my PC. Must be something at your end. Do you have JavaScript disabled? Ad/popup blocker? Use Chrome with the developer tools and watch what network resources are being loaded. You should be able to see all the files you expect to be loaded. There'll probably be one or more which are red indicating they've been blocked or something and you can diagnose from there.

Comment: You can see the chart? Good news! But you're the first one, I've tried at home and I sent the link to some other people and no-one is able to visualize it. So do you think that everything is due to browser configuration?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can still see it using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can access your chart from here but I see that the POST is on

http://ldvapp07.fao.org:8030/charts/api

while all the JS is loaded directly from the IP address:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://193.43.36.180:8030/charts/libs/JQuery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://193.43.36.180:8030/charts/libs/Highcharts/2.2.1/highcharts.js">
<script src="http://193.43.36.180:8030/charts/libs/Exporting/2.2.1/exporting.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://193.43.36.180:8030/charts/libs/CanvasTools/2.2.1/canvas-tools.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Try making these URL relative; It could be that the browser you are using thinks this is cross-site scripting because your machine configuration resolves ldvapp07.fao.org to a different IP address.

Comment: I can try this solution but I'm not sure it'll fix the issue, because I've also tried to save the HTML produced by the servlet as a file and open it with a browser, and I can see the chart then. I'll do this edit anyway, thanks a lot!